# Installing non market android app from DDMS

Tags: android

can I install android NON MARKET apps in my eclipse device emulator? There are many free non market apss there which I want to try.

If I get an apk file and try to PUSH into the emulator through DDMS view and then install it from the emulator, how should I proceed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dont push any apk file like that, try the following to install the NON MARKET APP apk file from your pc:

```
    go to your android sdk platform tools path like the following

for ex: C:/ProgramFIles/Android/android-sdk/platform-tools/ adb install "full path to your .apk file from your pc"

   like :  C:/ProgramFIles/Android/android-sdk/platform-tools/ adb install D:\Android\Workspace\Demo\bin\Demo.apk
```

and if you are running two emulators than the above solution does not work to install it needs to specify the emulatr device also like:

```
       for ex: C:/ProgramFIles/Android/android-sdk/platform-tools/ adb -s emulator-5554 install "full path to your .apk file from your pc"
```

Comment: THANX a lot , But can I install it from the emulator itself FROM google play ? the way we do in real device?

Comment: No , you cannot install any application from GOOGLE PLAY to emualtor directly